# Nested class AsyncTask can't modify Outer Class static objects

Tags: java, android, class, android-asynctask, inner-classes

I have a problem with Nested java class, it sees outer class object but somehow fails to modify it. I read a lot of similar questions but couldn't find solution for this one. It might be something really simple but I'm not good enough to figure it out.
I have Sorter class to do some calculations in the background, I decided to use AsyncTask to perform those calculations outside of UI Thread.
My class looks like this

```
public class Sorter
{
    private static List<Long> workingList;
    private static int _numberOfContainers, _containerSize, _timesToRepeat;
    private static Long _numbersFrom, _numbersTo, _sortingAlgorithmId;

    public Sorter(int numberOfContainers, int containerSize, Long numbersFrom, Long numbersTo,
                  int timesToRepeat, Long sortingAlgorithmId)
    {
        _numberOfContainers = numberOfContainers;
        _containerSize = containerSize;
        _numbersFrom = numbersFrom;
        _numbersTo = numbersTo;
        _timesToRepeat = timesToRepeat;
        _sortingAlgorithmId = sortingAlgorithmId;
        // perform calculations in the background
        new BackgroundCalculations().execute();
    }

    static class BackgroundCalculations extends AsyncTask<Void,Void,Void>
    {

        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(Void... voids)
        {
            workingList = new ArrayList<>(_containerSize);
            // workingList is still null after this
            _numbersTo += 1; // to fix exclusive number range to inclusive
            Random rand = new Random();
            for (int i = 0; i < _containerSize; i++)
            {
                workingList.add((long) (rand.nextDouble() * (_numbersTo - _numbersFrom)) + _numbersFrom))
            }
            // some calc
            return null;
        }
    }


}
```

I tried to instantiate workingList in Sorter constructor but nested class fails to add items to workingList anyway. Any solutions? Maybe better way to implement background calculations without such problems?

Comment: you need to override onpostExecute method of AsyncTask and pass the result in the form of arraylist from doInBackground method and then used that array list in onPostExecute method to instantiate workingList.

Comment: Hint: read about java coding styleguides. "_" has no place in variable names (unless for CONSTANTS_USING_MULTIPLE_WORDS)

Comment: @dex I tried to do it but I need to access outside class workingList because some calculations are made via outer class method. Should I move all calculations to AsyncTask class?

Comment: yes you can move all calculation inside background, as @GhostCat please follow java coding guidelines paradigms.

Comment: ok I rearranged my Sorter class completely so AsyncTask is outer and only class. And now everything is more clear and works. But I still don't understand why nested class couldn't modify outer class fields. Thanks for help, I'm glad to be able to learn new stuff :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are mixing up two concepts here.

Your methods are all static; and your fields are two. So why do you then use a constructor; indicating that you want an object of your Sorter class to be instantiated?

So, the first thing to fix your problem - get a better understanding of the concepts you are using.

Comment: static fields and methods are result of some similar questions that I've read, and it had helped there. Could you please give me a concrete idea of how to approach this situation to make it work? I'll remove constructor and leave it to default one and pass arguments to method, but that won't fix my problem.